# PySpark Dataframe - Convert a string column into Json Object

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a column in my pyspark dataframe which has a structure as below :

```
{"product_price":"13","product_name":"test","product_type":"test_product_type","product_brand:"test_brand","product_id":"26538"}
```

But the data type of this column is of type String . If i do the below ,

```
so_df.withColumn("product_details",to_json(so_df['product_data']))
```

Below is the error i get

```
cannot resolve 'structstojson(`product_data`)' due to data type mismatch: Input type string must be a struct, array of structs or a map or array of map .
```

Kindly let me know how to go about this as i need to convert this string into a json object or struct .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by example. I have added the value and what i am trying to do along with the error .

Comment: Can you give me some code by which I can create a small dataframe similar to yours?